# How to find $\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\left[(1+2x/3)^{1/x}\right]$ as $x$ tends to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

How do I find the limit: 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\left[(1+2x/3)^{1/x}\right] ?$$

I never saw such type of question in the whole chapter. Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the limit of $(\ln x)/x$ as $x\to+\infty$? Maybe you can apply a logarithm law to put your expression on something very similar-looking?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) to write
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+2x/3)}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{2/3}{1+2x/3}}{1}=0
$$

Comment: Yes I did this.. but I am unable to solve it..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$$

> Applying this to the expression gives:
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \ln(1+\frac{2x}{3})^\frac{1}{x} = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}\ln(1+\frac{2x}{3})$$

Continue using either known results, or by L'Hopital's rule.